# Nonparametric quantile regression curves to scatterplot

Tags: r, regression, scatter-plot, quantile

I created a scatterplot (multiple groups GRP) with `IV=time`, `DV=concentration`. I wanted to add the quantile regression curves `(0.025,0.05,0.5,0.95,0.975)` to my plot.

And by the way, this is what I did to create the scatter-plot:

```
attach(E)  ## E is the name I gave to my data
## Change Group to factor so that may work with levels in the legend
Group<-as.character(Group)
Group<-as.factor(Group)

## Make the colored scatter-plot
mycolors = c('red','orange','green','cornflowerblue')
plot(Time,Concentration,main="Template",xlab="Time",ylab="Concentration",pch=18,col=mycolors[Group])

## This also works identically
## with(E,plot(Time,Concentration,col=mycolors[Group],main="Template",xlab="Time",ylab="Concentration",pch=18))

## Use identify to identify each point by group number (to check)
## identify(Time,Concentration,col=mycolors[Group],labels=Group)
## Press Esc or press Stop to stop identify function

## Create legend
## Use locator(n=1,type="o") to find the point to align top left of legend box
legend('topright',legend=levels(Group),col=mycolors,pch=18,title='Group')
```

Because the data that I created here is a small subset of my larger data, it may look like it can be approximated as a rectangular hyperbole. But I don't want to call a mathematical relationship between my independent and dependent variables yet.

I think `nlrq` from the package `quantreg` may be the answer, but I don't understand how to use the function when I don't know the relationship between my variables.

I find this graph from a science article, and I want to do precisely the same kind of graph:
[image: Goal]

Again, thanks for your help!

**Update**

[Test.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8won4dz0bxk29qk/Test.csv)
I was pointed out that my sample data is not reproducible. Here is a sample of my data.

```
library(evd)
qcbvnonpar(p=c(0.025,0.05,0.5,0.95,0.975),cbind(TAD,DV),epmar=T,plot=F,add=T)
```

I also tried qcbvnonpar::evd,but the curve doesn't seem very smooth.

Comment: If you are unable to provide your own data, try creating a dataset of random numbers and demonstrate your problem. Show us what you've tried. It gives us something to work with as well as being a sign of good faith.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry--I will make some numbers up. It may be rather large.

Comment: This may help you in generating data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: A couple of comments: the figure you show appears to be from http://works.bepress.com/phil_reiss/16/ ? That paper appears to have an associated R package (haven't looked at it ...) It's going to be rather hard (I think) to get completely nonparametric, smooth quantiles. Two possible solutions are (1) fit generalized additive models (e.g. `library(splines); rq(y~s(x,5),tau=0.9)`); (2) use running estimates of the quantiles.

Comment: How big is your data set?

Comment: maybe rqss() from quantreg may also suit you?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik: I will save this page for future reference. It seems my question isn't reproducible with a smaller dataset, and I think I saw someone post a dropbox link to a large file, and I may do the same in the future

Comment: @BenBolker: Oh, I should have cited: [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811911001248). I thought I replied yesterday but the comment didn't show up, my n=1000 approximately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have in the past frequently struggled with `rqss` and my issues have almost always been related to the ordering of the points.

You have multiple measurements at various time points, which is why you're getting different lengths. This works for me:

```
dat <- read.csv("~/Downloads/Test.csv")

library(quantreg)
dat <- plyr::arrange(dat,Time)
fit<-rqss(Concentration~qss(Time,constraint="N"),tau=0.5,data = dat)
with(dat,plot(Time,Concentration))
lines(unique(dat$Time)[-1],fit$coef[1] + fit$coef[-1])
```

[image]

Sorting the data frame prior to fitting the model appears necessary.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. I didn't know that ordering could be an issue.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe have a look at quantreg:::rqss for smoothing splines and quantile regression.
Sorry for the not so nice example data:

```
set.seed(1234)
period <- 100
x <- 1:100
y <- sin(2*pi*x/period) + runif(length(x),-1,1)


require(quantreg)
mod <- rqss(y ~ qss(x))
mod2 <- rqss(y ~ qss(x), tau=0.75)
mod3 <- rqss(y ~ qss(x), tau=0.25)
plot(x, y)
lines(x[-1], mod$coef[1] + mod$coef[-1], col = 'red')
lines(x[-1], mod2$coef[1] + mod2$coef[-1], col = 'green')
lines(x[-1], mod3$coef[1] + mod3$coef[-1], col = 'green')
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `rqss()` - if non-parametric is what is required and the example image suggests it is a spline-based fit then `rqss()` is certainly the first place I would look.

Comment: It works so beautifully with your example, but I am not sure why, I keep getting `Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ` warning for my dataset even though I check that my x and y have the same n. Still working on error debugging :P

Comment: Can you give use a little more of your data? Your example data from above is obviously not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want `ggplot2` graphic...

I based this example on that of @EDi.  I increased the `x` and `y` so that the quantile lines would be less wiggly.  Because of this increase, I need to use `unique(x)` in place of `x` in some of the calls.

Here's the modified set-up:

```
set.seed(1234)
period <- 100
x <- rep(1:100,each=100)
y <- 1*sin(2*pi*x/period) + runif(length(x),-1,1)


require(quantreg)
mod <- rqss(y ~ qss(x))
mod2 <- rqss(y ~ qss(x), tau=0.75)
mod3 <- rqss(y ~ qss(x), tau=0.25)
```

Here are the two plots:

```
# @EDi's base graphics example
plot(x, y)
lines(unique(x)[-1], mod$coef[1] + mod$coef[-1], col = 'red')
lines(unique(x)[-1], mod2$coef[1] + mod2$coef[-1], col = 'green')
lines(unique(x)[-1], mod3$coef[1] + mod3$coef[-1], col = 'green')
```

[image]

```
# @swihart's ggplot2 example:
## get into dataset so that ggplot2 can have some fun:
qrdf <- data.table(x       = unique(x)[-1],
                   median =  mod$coef[1] +  mod$coef[-1],
                   qupp   = mod2$coef[1] + mod2$coef[-1],
                   qlow   = mod3$coef[1] + mod3$coef[-1]
)

line_size = 2
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y),
             color="black", alpha=0.5) +
  ## quantiles:
  geom_line(data=qrdf,aes(x=x, y=median),
            color="red", alpha=0.7, size=line_size) +
  geom_line(data=qrdf,aes(x=x, y=qupp),
            color="blue", alpha=0.7, size=line_size, lty=1) +
  geom_line(data=qrdf,aes(x=x, y=qlow),
            color="blue", alpha=0.7, size=line_size, lty=1)
```

[image]